# Same x axis length in ggplot2 with categorial data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created some line graphs for a psychological eye tracking experiment. Therefore, I need different plots with the same x axis length (independent of the size / name of the legend). The x axis describes categorial data and for this scenario, I didn't find any solution.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  dat1 <- data.frame(
    Bildschirmgröße = factor(c("klein","klein","groß","groß")),
    Gehalt = factor(c("niedrig","hoch","niedrig","hoch"), 
                        levels = c("niedrig","hoch")),
    Apps = c(15, 24,34,29))

 ## Plot
  lg_51_k <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=Gehalt, y=Apps, 
                      shape=Bildschirmgröße, group=Bildschirmgröße))+
    geom_line(aes(color = Bildschirmgröße),size=2)+
    theme_classic(base_size=18, )+
    theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 2))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"))+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))+
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#0000ff"))+
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"))+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5, face = "bold"))+
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=+1.5, face = "bold"))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, by=4), limits = c(0,40))+
    ylab("Anzahl Apps")


  ## Ausgabe
  lg_51_k
```

Thx.

Comment: Can you expand your example to include another plot where the x axis is not the same length? One way to ensure matching axes in ggplot2 is to use `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()` (which would require combining all the data into a single data.frame).

Comment: Well, is there anything wrong with my answer? Please take the time and give us some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to control the size of the legend. So if you set them big enough, they will all be that one size.

One way to do it is with the `legend.size.key` setting, used like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
dat1 <- data.frame(
  Bildschirmgröße = factor(c("klein","klein","groß","groß")),
  Gehalt = factor(c("niedrig","hoch","niedrig","hoch"), 
                  levels = c("niedrig","hoch")),
  Apps = c(15, 24,34,29))

## Plot
lg_51_k <- ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=Gehalt, y=Apps, 
            shape=Bildschirmgröße,      group=Bildschirmgröße))+
  geom_line(aes(color = Bildschirmgröße),size=2)+
  theme_classic(base_size=18, )+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 2))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#0000ff"))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=16, face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5, face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=+1.5, face = "bold"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40, by=4), limits = c(0,40))+
  ylab("Anzahl Apps") +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(6, "cm"))


## Ausgabe
lg_51_k
```

[image]